# Como passar o conteúdo de um arquivo.txt para um vetor em JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou com esse problema, gostaria de saber o que vocês me sugerem pesquisar para resolvê-lo.
Tentei utilizar o .split, FileReader.
Pode ser em Js, Jquery ou Ajax. Qualquer sugestão é bem-vinda. Pesquisei sobre o assunto mas não encontrei nada concreto sobre esse meu problema. Agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Comment: Mas qual é o conteúdo do arquivo txt?

Comment: Primeiro voce precis carregar o arquivo txt, ai voce usa ajax, a partir da ai voce ja vai ter o conteudo do txt como string, ai é só manipular ele. Como nao tem mais informacoes fica dificil dar exemplos. se puder colocar o conteudo ou trecho do txt ajuda bastante

Comment: jbueno, apenas números.

Comment: @NeuberOliveira, o conteúdo são apenas números, podendo ser 1 em cada linha ou separados por vírgula.

Answer (score 1):

Isso resolve, a menos que o seu arquivo.txt esteja muita caotico.

```
var numsList = [];
$.ajax( 'arquivo.txt', {
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(response){
        //response é o conteudo do arquivo.txt
        var lines = response.split('\n'); //quebra o arquivo em linhas, 
        for(var i in lines){
            var row = lines[i];
            var nums = row.split(','); //quebra a linha em valores separdos por virgula
            for(var j in nums){
                var num = parseInt(nums[j]); //converte o valor para int
                if( !isNaN(num) ) //basicamente verifica se é um numero
                    numsList.push(num); //adiciona o item no array
            }
        }

        console.log(numsList);
    }
});
```

Testei o codigo em um arquivo txt com o seguinte conteudo

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,

11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
21, 22, 23, 24, 25,26, 27, 28, 29, 30
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Neuber Oliveira, tentarei seguir essa linha de raciocínio. Quanto ao arquivo.txt que você utilizou foi local?

Comment: Sim foi local, mas via ajax como esta carrega de praticamente qualquer url

Answer (score 0):

De forma bem simples:

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var res = this.responseText;
      alert(res); //  A Variável res terá o conteúdo.
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "seu_arquivo_txt.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Olha no Console se está encontrando o arquivo numeros.txt

Comment: tentei digitar os números em forma de string e mesmo assim o alert não roda. fiz a var res = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"

Comment: @Caraujo abre o teu console (f12 no chrome e vai na aba console) e verifica se o arquivo `numeros.txt`está sendo encontrado

Comment: tens razão, não está sendo encontrado.
Aparece o seguinte erro:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/cassi/Documents/Projeto%20de%20Pesquisa/projeto-de-pesquisa/Arquivos%20Javascript/numeros.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Alguma sugestão de como resolver?

Comment: Cross Origin? Em que pasta está teu HTML? (tem MUITOS espaços nos nomes das tuas pastas (os '%20'), se possível remova eles)

Comment: eliminei os espaços, o erro continua

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/cassi/Documents/ArqJs/numeros.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: @Caraujo Teu HTML está nessa pasta: "C:/Users/cassi/Documents/ArqJs/"?

Comment: está. Junto com o arquivo txt

Comment: @Caraujo Tu está rodando isso dentro do WAMP? Ou apenas abrindo o arquivo html? Porque se tu simplesmente jogar o HTML no navegador, não vai funcionar nunca, justamente por esse erro de Cross, mas dentro de um server a solução que montei pra ti funciona.

Comment: agradeço a ajuda, estava rodando direto no navegador, por isso o erro. Agora rodando no Xampp funcionou direitinho.